# escape single qoute in ffmpeg filename varible php

Tags: php, ffmpeg, escaping

code works fine but if the filename has a single qoute just as  "Britney's video.mp4" it does not work.

```
$ffmpeg = "/usb/bin/local/ffmpeg";
$videos = "/videos/*.mp4";
$ouput_path = "/videos/thumbnails/";


foreach(glob($videos) as $video_file){

$lfilename = basename($video_file);
$filename = basename($video_file, ".mp4");
$thumbnail = $ouput_path.$filename.'.jpg';
if (!file_exists($filename)) {
#$thumbnail = str_replace("'", "%27", $thumbnail);
exec("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i '$video_file' -an -y -f mjpeg -ss 00:00:30 -vframes 1 '$thumbnail'");
}
echo "<a href='$lfilename'>$filename<img src='thumbnails/$filename.jpg' width='350'>";
```

Comment: You could use http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php on `$video_file` and `$thumbnail`.

Comment: thanks i wouldnt know how to use it or put it  . just seems overly complicated..

Comment: Did click the link supplied? It explains what it does. `escapeshellarg() adds single quotes around a string and quotes/escapes any existing single quotes allowing you to pass a string directly to a shell function and having it be treated as a single safe argument.`

Comment: thanks i did visit it but i dont know where to put it ....... or how.

Comment: Do you understand what the manual page says/what your code is doing? Where are you hung up?

Comment: You don't need `-an` when outputting images.

Comment: i removed -an still can not use ffmpeg with a file that contains a '

Comment: It was just a suggestion, not a solution to the problem or else I would have left an answer.

Answer (score 1):

i got it working but not using something overly complicated.
thanks all

```
$comd = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i \"$video_file\" -y -f mjpeg -ss 00:00:30 -vframes 1 \"$thumbnail\" 2>&1"; shell_exec($comd);
shell_exec($comd);
```

Answer (score -1):

As suggested in the comments, you can just wrap all your shell-command String within the `escapeshellarg()` as shown below.

```
<?php

    foreach(glob($videos) as $video_file){
        $lfilename = basename($video_file);
        $filename  = basename($video_file, ".mp4");
        $thumbnail = $ouput_path.$filename.'.jpg';

        if (!file_exists($filename)) {
            $cmd         = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i ";
            $cmd        .= $video_file . " -an -y -f mjpeg -ss 00:00:30 ";
            $cmd        .= "-vframes 1 " . $thumbnail;

            exec( escapeshellarg($cmd) );
        }
```

Comment: if i remove   escapeshellarg to         exec(($cmd)); it works but still does not work with file names with ' such as Britney's Video

Comment: i got it working using $comd = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i \"$video_file\" -y -f mjpeg -ss 00:00:30 -vframes 1 \"$thumbnail\" 2>&1";
shell_exec($comd);

Comment: but how can i make it glob mp4s, avi not just mp4  ? thank you